# SpresenseでFLASHにデータを上書きで書き込みたい

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDEを使いCプログラムを書いています。
プログラムの中でSDが壊れた時、電源が一度切れた時、
リブートが走り再びプログラムを動き始めます。
この時リブート前のデータを利用したいので、FLASHにデータを書き込みます。
以下のサンプルを参考に、FLASHのマウントなどの手続き、処理をしてみました。
しかし、リブート前に書き込んだ位置に、リブート後に同じ位置に書き込みができずにいます。
FLASHのtest.txtに、リブート前に"1"と書き込んだ所に、リブート後"2"を上書きしたいのですが、"12"となります。("2"だけFLASHに入るようにしたい）
seekを使うと上書きできるようですので試しましたが、うまくできませんでした。

文字の("1" or "2")、 数字の(1 or 2)、両方でseekを使ったサンプルがあれば教えて下さい。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/blob/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/libraries/Flash/examples/read_write/read_write.ino
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/blob/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/libraries/File/examples/read_write/read_write.ino

質問に過不足ありましたら別途回答を致します。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: あなた自身が実際に試したコードを質問中に追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

機種はspresenseのメインボードを利用しています。
「フラッシュメモリ、っていうのは上書きはできません」という事を知りませんでした。ありがとうございました。
Spresense Arduino ライブラリを見ると、「ブロックのイレーズ」はありませんでしたが、
「Flash.remove()　Flash デバイス内のファイルを削除します。」がありました。ありがとうございました。

https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html

Comment: 「フラッシュメモリは上書きできない」というのは質問の文脈に対して正しい回答ではないです。質問のコメントにあるとおり実際に試したコードを追記してください。

Answer (score -1):

コードも使用機種もないので一般論でしか回答できませんが、、
ふつう、フラッシュメモリ、っていうのは上書きはできません
一旦そのブロックのイレーズを行い、（ブロック内のデータも含めて）書き込み直す、という操作を行う必要があります